# Calculating Velocity from Speed, X,Y Bearing, and Z Bearing

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I'm not entirely sure how to go about it, but I have a data structure that gives me

```
Speed
Bearing - Direction in the XY Plane 
Z-Bearing - Direction in the Z Plane
```

How can I combine these into a 3 dimensional velocity vector?

I assume it's something like

```
Xvel = cos(bearing) * speed * cos(Z-Bearing)
Yvel = sin(bearing) * speed * cos(Z-Bearing)
Zvel = sin(Z-Bearing)
```

Buut I'm not entirely sure I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have it correct, presuming the interpretation of $Z$-plane (which doesn't quite make sense) works.

You do want `Zvel = speed * sin(Z-Bearing)` though.

See [Spherical coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), where the usual convention is that $Z$-bearing $0$ is directly in the $Z$-direction, so flip mentions of `sin` and `cos(Z-bearing)`.

Comment: yeah,forgetting * speed was a typo on my part.